# Get the unread mail count gmail in Android

Tags: android, gmail-api

I want to get an int with the number of unread emails in the accounts of the device. I have seen that there is a new way to do this using the "Gmail Labels Public API"

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/04/gmail-public-labels-api.html

I have read the documentation and downloaded the sample application and it really works. But I have two problems: (

My intention is to get an int with the number of unread conversations, i try this:

```
 public static int getUnreadGmailCount(Context context) {

    ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(GmailContract.Labels.getLabelsUri("ensisinfo102@gmail.com"),
            null,
            null, null,
            null);
    if (cursor == null || cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Log.d(TAG, "No Gmail inbox information found for account.");
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
        return 0;
    }
    int count = 0;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        if (CANONICAL_NAME_INBOX_CATEGORY_PRIMARY.equals(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CANONICAL_NAME)))) {
            count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS));
            System.out.println("count is====>"+count);
            break;
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return count;
}
```

but not works, always returns "0",But in gmail i have 3 unread messages

really appreciate any help

thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

You can [**get a label**](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/labels/get) and check the `messagesUnread`. The `INBOX` label is probably what you want:

**Request**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/labels/INBOX?access_token={ACCESS_TOKEN}
```

**Response**

```
{
 "id": "INBOX",
 "name": "INBOX",
 "messageListVisibility": "hide",
 "labelListVisibility": "labelShow",
 "type": "system",
 "messagesTotal": 4527,
 "messagesUnread": 4498,
 "threadsTotal": 4168,
 "threadsUnread": 4154
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tholle i updated my code i followed http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/04/gmail-public-labels-api.html

Comment: i am not understanding what your saying can you pleasee explain me clearly

Answer (score 0):

Please read carefully this [document](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/android) and also check this [one](http://android.techjaffa.xyz/gmail-5-0-how-to-get-label-information-for-gmails-exchange-feature/)