# How to get Number of Unread mails count from Gmail account

Tags: android, gmail-api

Hi i am trying to find Number of unread mails count from my Gmail account for this i searched lot in Google but i did not get
any working solution and finally i found one document from below link i followed same process but it returns always Unread mails count as 0 but in Gmail account there is 2 Unread messages

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2012/04/gmail-public-labels-api.html

Can some one help me please i am waiting for correct solution since 3 days

```
public static int getGmailCount(Context context) {

        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(GmailContract.Labels.getLabelsUri("ensisinfo102@gmail.com"),
                null,
                null, null,
                null);
        if (cursor == null || cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "No Gmail inbox information found for account.");
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
            return 0;
        }
        int count = 0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            if (CANONICAL_NAME_INBOX_CATEGORY_PRIMARY.equals(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CANONICAL_NAME)))) {
                count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS));
                System.out.println("count is====>" + count);
                break;
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return count;
    }
```

Comment: Check the answer in this question. I think "threadsUnread" 
 is what you need .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499338/get-the-unread-mail-count-gmail-in-android

Comment: there is no solution from link provide by your-->https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499338/get-the-unread-mail-count-gmail-in-android

Comment: if want i will share my sample code to yours please suggest me

Comment: Can you change your code to this and try `cursor.getInt(GmailContract.Labels.NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS)`

Comment: did you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3037279/5545429)?

Comment: @Sunil sunny i will try and tell result now

Comment: @Hi Shinil M that is old one works upto Api level 22

Comment: GmailContract.Labels.NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS) returns like "numUnreadConversations" which is wrong

Comment: @Hi sunil sunny your try this when ever?,If try what is solutuin to my question

Comment: @Krish See my edit.. I was able to print the unreadCount.

Comment: i will let try and will tell result

Comment: is this print what we logged gmail account  in our device

Comment: i have only 1 unread message but it's printing 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never tried this but can you try this.

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    AccountManager accountManager;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
         accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
        Account account= getAccount(accountManager);
        Log.d("MainActivity","UnreadCount-----> "+getUnreadCount(account.name));
    }
    public Account getAccount(AccountManager accountManager) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            return null;
        }
        Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
        Account account;
        if (accounts.length > 0) {
            account = accounts[0];
        } else {
            account = null;
        }
        return account;
    }
    public int getUnreadCount(String accountName) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
                GmailContract.Labels.getLabelsUri(accountName),
                UnreadQuery.PROJECTION, null, null, null
        );
        try {
            if (cursor == null || cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                return 0;
            }

            int unread = 0;
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                String canonicalName = cursor.getString(UnreadQuery.CANONICAL_NAME);
                int unreadInLabel = cursor.getInt(UnreadQuery.NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS);
                if (GmailContract.Labels.LabelCanonicalNames.CANONICAL_NAME_INBOX_CATEGORY_PRIMARY.equals(canonicalName)) {
                    unread = Math.max(unread, unreadInLabel);
                }
            }
            return unread;
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
        }
    }

    private interface UnreadQuery {
        String[] PROJECTION = {
                GmailContract.Labels.NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS,
                GmailContract.Labels.CANONICAL_NAME,
        };
        int NUM_UNREAD_CONVERSATIONS = 0;
        int CANONICAL_NAME = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: i will let try and tell result

Comment: no its not working,I mean controller not enter inside if loop and can you please in ur system once and pleas update me

Comment: Ok. I have no time for testing this. But I just used this https://github.com/johnsto/mailcircle project and was able to print the unread count. https://github.com/johnsto/mailcircle/blob/master/app/src/main/java/uk/co/johnsto/mailcircle/NotificationService.java -> getUnreadCount() try to implement this.

Comment: Or you can use this https://github.com/fnk0/DashclockInbox/blob/master/app/src/main/java/gabilheri/com/inboxdashclock/InboxExtension.java which I think is a better one.

Comment: OK send it to sunilsunny565@gmail.com.. I will look into it when I have time.